# How can I convert List<T?> to List<T>?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function with a return type of `List<T?>?`. I know that I can use the `!` operator to convert this return type to `List<T?>`, but how do I then convert this to a `List<T>`?

Code that I've tried:

```
// testFunction returns List<T?>?
var test = testFunction() as List<T>? ?? [];
```

Result:

```
The following _CastError was thrown building ...:
type 'List<T?>' is not a subtype of type 'List<T>?' in type cast
```

Comment: You'll have to `map` over the elements and turn each from a `T?` to a `T`. How would you like to handle the nulls? You have three options: 1) force-unwrap and crash (asserting that none of the values should ever be null), 2) substitute a default value with `??`, or 3) `filter` the null elements out and only keep the non-null values.

Comment: That worked! Thank you @Alexander - I assumed the answer would be some obscure notation that I hadn't yet stumbled upon. Thankfully not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three solutions

- This will add and replace null values in a with a default value in b

```
    List<T?>? a = [];
    List<T>? b = a.map((e) => e ?? defaultValue).toList();
```

- These doesn't consider null values

```
    List<T?>? a = [];
    List<T> b2 = a.filter((v) => v != null).toList();
```

```
    List<T?>? a = [];

    List<int>? b2 = [];
    a.forEach((e) {
      if (e != null) b2.add(e);
    });
```

Comment: You can also rewrite the second example as `List<T> b2 = a.filter((v) => v != null).toList();`

Comment: @enzo thanks i'll add it